# react useEffect strange behaviour - can't explain?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in a useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMessages() {
      let messages = [];

      const firestore = firebase.firestore();
      const query = firestore.collection('chats').where("repliedTo", "==", false).where("type", "==", "StudentQuery").orderBy("timestamp", "desc"); 
  
      query.onSnapshot({
        next: (querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log("x ", doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            messages.push({mid: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
            console.log(messages)
          });
        },
      });
      setMessagesList(messages)
      setMessageCount(messagesList.length)
      console.log('xxxx' + messagesList.length)    
    }
    fetchMessages();
  }, [messagesList.length]);
```

A few things seem to be wrong with this and I can't see it.

1. When I trigger this code (by inserting a new record into Firestore) what I expect would be to see a console.log  with the (final) array size (so previous array size + 1) - but instead what I am seeing is the previous array + (previous array + 1 entry)  I would have thought he `let messages = []` would have cleared the array every time an update happened?
2. I never see the console.log("xxx") in my console.  I want to put a state update here as this line should be safe as the database read has done, but since the line doesn't appear I don't know what's going wrong.

Can anyone shed some insight?

Comment: If I am not wrong the firebase call is async so you need to wait for the promise to resolve! This should be the reason for strange behavior. Try console.log(query) after the firebase call.

Comment: Are you using another useEffect in this component?

Comment: There is another useEffect, I had read that 2 useEffects could be used

Answer (score 1):

I've not used firebase before but it looks like you're effectively creating a subscription which is getting called outside of React's render cycle.

You could just add a state property that you update when `next` is called, eg:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

// Use the `useEffect` to set up / tear down the subscription
useEffect(() => {
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    const query = firestore.collection(...);

    const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot({
        next: (querySnapshot) => {
            setMessages(prev => [
                ...prev, 
                ...querySnapshot.map(doc => ({
                    mid: doc.id, 
                    ...doc.data(),
                })),
            ]);
        });
    });

    // Unsubscribe when you unmount
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, [])
```

Comment: slight update on this - I've caught an error appearing in the console and it looks like my query requires an index - not sure if that will be causing any issues

Comment: I've added an index on the Firestore table and now that error disappears.  However, this useEffect is still not working as expected.  In the console, I can see my "messages" array, but when I try to use this, I get nothing appearing.  I am at a loss to explain why

Comment: Have you changed the code over as I suggested above? If so, if you add a `console.log(querySnapshot)` inside the `next` callback, what does it show?

Comment: I did try your code - the was an extra } and ; to get this to compile.  When the code ran "Uncaught TypeError: querySnapshot.map is not a function or its return value is not iterable" on line 92 which is the one setMessages(prev=> [

Comment: Ah ok. I thought `querySnapshot` was an array but obviously not :|

Comment: No worries. I decided to remove this from my app and just replace with a static icon